# Tor status Active: Failed

Tags: connection

I don't know how to properly explain this, but i think the picture would help me explain.

After getting read of the error "Permission denied", i restarted tor, copied down my tor hidden service onion link `http://xabkqgk7mcl3o3zncmefo5yhlbuwvwhxkgfxirtsiuj67zour7ij32qd.onion/`, which i searched in the tor browser and the result came out "Server not found". I decided to check my tor status with `sudo system status tor@default` and the result which is the in the picture....
[image].

**Question**
-What might have gone wrong and how do i resolve the issue and get my site to be running.

*Thank you.*

**EDIT:**

- So i typed in `sudo systemctl start tor@default` and the output was

```
Job for tor@default.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tor@default.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

- I typed in this second code `sudo journalctl -u tor@default` the output has up to more than 1000 lines of code, so i don't know how to paste all of it here.

```
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.983 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, Ope>
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.993 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe >
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.995 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults->
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.995 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.999 [warn] /home/drago/hidden_service/ is not owned by this user (debian-t>
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.999 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous>
May 25 12:18:52 drago-VirtualBox tor[2659]: May 25 12:18:52.999 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.224 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, Ope>
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.227 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe >
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.227 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults->
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.227 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.234 [warn] /home/drago/hidden_service/ is not owned by this user (debian-t>
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.234 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous>
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2663]: May 25 12:18:53.235 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2667]: May 25 12:18:53.495 [notice] Tor 0.4.2.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, Ope>
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2667]: May 25 12:18:53.496 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe >
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2667]: May 25 12:18:53.496 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults->
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2667]: May 25 12:18:53.496 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 25 12:18:53 drago-VirtualBox tor[2667]: May 25 12:18:53.506 [warn] /home/drago/hidden_service/ is not owned by this user (debian-t>
lines 1145-1178
```

Comment: Run `sudo systemctl start tor@default` and `sudo journalctl -u tor@default`, then paste the results into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your hidden service directory cannot be in a home directory as it's not allowed by the systemd service's security policy. Instead you can use the path `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service`, and make sure you set the owner to `debian-tor`.

Comment: I changed my hidden service dir from `HiddenServiceDir /home/drago/hidden_service/` to  `HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/`. I typed `tor` and the error message i got was  
`May 28 09:48:13.232 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
May 28 09:48:13.240 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ cannot be read: Permission denied
May 28 09:48:13.242 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
May 28 09:48:13.242 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.`

Comment: Also another thing. I don't know how to set the owner to `debian-tor`

Comment: @ClintonVega Are you running tor as a service or running tor directly? You cannot mix them like that. For setting the owner, look up the `chown` command.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo chown -R debian-tor: /var/lib/tor`
`sudo systemctl restart tor@default.service`
`sudo systemctl status tor@default.service`